# Using photoswipe run a iframe video in lightbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, photoswipe

i'm using photoswipe to view images in lightbox and also iframe videos too.but is not working in iframe.how can i code to view videos in photoswipe lighbox.

and i try this.

**HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/photoswipe.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/default-skin.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="video_bg video_gallery" data-pswp-uid="1">
    <a class="hide_480"  data-med-size="1024x1024" data-med="assets/images/dynamic/video.jpg" data-size="961x577" 
                        href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/i9LZXE--CV0">
        <iframe width="961" height="577" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="1" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lEhu2cFvDe8?wmode=opaque?rel=0?autoplay=1&html5=1"></iframe>                
    </a>
</div>

<script src="assets/js/photoswipe.min.js"></script> 
<script src="assets/js/photoswipe-ui-default.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
 (function() {

        var initPhotoSwipeFromDOM = function(gallerySelector) {

            var parseThumbnailElements = function(el) {
                var thumbElements = el.childNodes,
                    numNodes = thumbElements.length,
                    items = [],
                    el,
                    childElements,
                    thumbnailEl,
                    size,
                    item;

                for(var i = 0; i < numNodes; i++) {
                    el = thumbElements[i];

                    // include only element nodes 
                    if(el.nodeType !== 1) {
                      continue;
                    }

                    childElements = el.children;

                    size = el.getAttribute('data-size').split('x');

                    // create slide object
                    item = {
                        src: el.getAttribute('href'),
                        w: parseInt(size[0], 10),
                        h: parseInt(size[1], 10),
                        author: el.getAttribute('data-author')
                    };

                    item.el = el; // save link to element for getThumbBoundsFn

                    if(childElements.length > 0) {
                      item.msrc = childElements[0].getAttribute('src'); // thumbnail url
                      if(childElements.length > 1) {
                          item.title = childElements[1].innerHTML; // caption (contents of figure)
                      }
                    }


                    var mediumSrc = el.getAttribute('data-med');
                    if(mediumSrc) {
                        size = el.getAttribute('data-med-size').split('x');
                        // "medium-sized" image
                        item.m = {
                            src: mediumSrc,
                            w: parseInt(size[0], 10),
                            h: parseInt(size[1], 10)
                        };
                    }
                    // original image
                    item.o = {
                        src: item.src,
                        w: item.w,
                        h: item.h
                    };

                    items.push(item);
                }

                return items;
            };

            // find nearest parent element
            var closest = function closest(el, fn) {
                return el && ( fn(el) ? el : closest(el.parentNode, fn) );
            };

            var onThumbnailsClick = function(e) {
                e = e || window.event;
                e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;

                var eTarget = e.target || e.srcElement;

                var clickedListItem = closest(eTarget, function(el) {
                    return el.tagName === 'A';
                });

                if(!clickedListItem) {
                    return;
                }

                var clickedGallery = clickedListItem.parentNode;

                var childNodes = clickedListItem.parentNode.childNodes,
                    numChildNodes = childNodes.length,
                    nodeIndex = 0,
                    index;

                for (var i = 0; i < numChildNodes; i++) {
                    if(childNodes[i].nodeType !== 1) { 
                        continue; 
                    }

                    if(childNodes[i] === clickedListItem) {
                        index = nodeIndex;
                        break;
                    }
                    nodeIndex++;
                }

                if(index >= 0) {
                    openPhotoSwipe( index, clickedGallery );
                }
                return false;
            };

            var photoswipeParseHash = function() {
                var hash = window.location.hash.substring(1),
                params = {};

                if(hash.length < 5) { // pid=1
                    return params;
                }

                var vars = hash.split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
                    if(!vars[i]) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    var pair = vars[i].split('=');  
                    if(pair.length < 2) {
                        continue;
                    }           
                    params[pair[0]] = pair[1];
                }

                if(params.gid) {
                    params.gid = parseInt(params.gid, 10);
                }

                return params;
            };

            var openPhotoSwipe = function(index, galleryElement, disableAnimation, fromURL) {
                var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0],
                    gallery,
                    options,
                    items;

                items = parseThumbnailElements(galleryElement);

                // define options (if needed)
                options = {

                    galleryUID: galleryElement.getAttribute('data-pswp-uid'),

                    getThumbBoundsFn: function(index) {
                        // See Options->getThumbBoundsFn section of docs for more info
                        var thumbnail = items[index].el.children[0],
                            pageYScroll = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop,
                            rect = thumbnail.getBoundingClientRect(); 

                        return {x:rect.left, y:rect.top + pageYScroll, w:rect.width};
                    },

                    addCaptionHTMLFn: function(item, captionEl, isFake) {
                        if(!item.title) {
                            captionEl.children[0].innerText = '';
                            return false;
                        }
                        captionEl.children[0].innerHTML = item.title +  '<br/><small>Photo: ' + item.author + '</small>';
                        return true;
                    }

                };


                if(fromURL) {
                    if(options.galleryPIDs) {
                        // parse real index when custom PIDs are used 
                        // http://photoswipe.com/documentation/faq.html#custom-pid-in-url
                        for(var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
                            if(items[j].pid == index) {
                                options.index = j;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        options.index = parseInt(index, 10) - 1;
                    }
                } else {
                    options.index = parseInt(index, 10);
                }

                // exit if index not found
                if( isNaN(options.index) ) {
                    return;
                }



                var radios = document.getElementsByName('gallery-style');
                for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
                    if (radios[i].checked) {
                        if(radios[i].id == 'radio-all-controls') {

                        } else if(radios[i].id == 'radio-minimal-black') {
                            options.mainClass = 'pswp--minimal--dark';
                            options.barsSize = {top:0,bottom:0};
                            options.captionEl = false;
                            options.fullscreenEl = false;
                            options.shareEl = false;
                            options.bgOpacity = 0.85;
                            options.tapToClose = true;
                            options.tapToToggleControls = false;
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if(disableAnimation) {
                    options.showAnimationDuration = 0;
                }

                // Pass data to PhotoSwipe and initialize it
                gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);

                // see: http://photoswipe.com/documentation/responsive-images.html
                var realViewportWidth,
                    useLargeImages = false,
                    firstResize = true,
                    imageSrcWillChange;

                gallery.listen('beforeResize', function() {

                    var dpiRatio = window.devicePixelRatio ? window.devicePixelRatio : 1;
                    dpiRatio = Math.min(dpiRatio, 2.5);
                    realViewportWidth = gallery.viewportSize.x * dpiRatio;


                    if(realViewportWidth >= 1200 || (!gallery.likelyTouchDevice && realViewportWidth > 800) || screen.width > 1200 ) {
                        if(!useLargeImages) {
                            useLargeImages = true;
                            imageSrcWillChange = true;
                        }

                    } else {
                        if(useLargeImages) {
                            useLargeImages = false;
                            imageSrcWillChange = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if(imageSrcWillChange && !firstResize) {
                        gallery.invalidateCurrItems();
                    }

                    if(firstResize) {
                        firstResize = false;
                    }

                    imageSrcWillChange = false;

                });

                gallery.listen('gettingData', function(index, item) {
                    if( useLargeImages ) {
                        item.src = item.o.src;
                        item.w = item.o.w;
                        item.h = item.o.h;
                    } else {
                        item.src = item.m.src;
                        item.w = item.m.w;
                        item.h = item.m.h;
                    }
                });

                gallery.init();
            };

            // select all gallery elements
            var galleryElements = document.querySelectorAll( gallerySelector );
            for(var i = 0, l = galleryElements.length; i < l; i++) {
                galleryElements[i].setAttribute('data-pswp-uid', i+1);
                galleryElements[i].onclick = onThumbnailsClick;
            }

            // Parse URL and open gallery if it contains #&pid=3&gid=1
            var hashData = photoswipeParseHash();
            if(hashData.pid && hashData.gid) {
                openPhotoSwipe( hashData.pid,  galleryElements[ hashData.gid - 1 ], true, true );
            }
        };

        initPhotoSwipeFromDOM('.video_gallery');

    })();
```

i have no idea what to do.i don't know its possible or not. and thanks in advance.

Comment: See [here](http://photoswipe.com/documentation/custom-html-in-slides.html) and read the 3rd bullet

Comment: thanks for that note. @JcDenton86

Answer (score 1):

In my jAlbum PhotoSwipe skin, see http://jalbum.net/nl/skins/skin/PhotoSwipe ,
I use a very simple solution for a video:

```
// build items array
var items = [
  {
    html: '<video controls autoplay><source src="slides/IMG_4979.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>'
  },
```

To see it in action, click the 3th thumbnail of the PhotoSwipe skin sample album: http://andrewolff.jalbum.net/Reestdal_PS/